# Iam trying to read data from my database using myCommand.Parameters.Add() but it is returning 0 results

Tags: c#

I am trying to read data from my database table **USERS WHERE DELYN** is **NO** and **USER_CD** is **01** but it is showing me that no such rows exists yet I have that rows(records) in my database, Iam thinking it is probably the 2 lines  ***myCommand.Parameters.Add()*** but am not sure how to fix this?

```
DataTable dataTable2 = new DataTable();
dataTable2.Columns.Add("NAME");
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=dbname;User Id=dbuser;Password=dbpass;"))
using (SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT NAME FROM USERS WHERE DELYN = @DELYN AND USER_CD =@USER_CD";
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DELYN", "NO");
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER_CD", "01");

    using (SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DataRow dataRow = dataTable2.NewRow();
                dataRow["NAME"] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("NAME"));
                dataTable2.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No rows found in Database Table.");
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of your `USER_CD` column? If it's an integer, it would be worth specifying an integer value instead of a string. (Personally I don't like `AddWithValue` - I'd call `Add` specifying the name and the type, then set the `Value` property, e.g. `myCommand.Parameters.Add("@DELYN", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "NO"`)

Comment: USER_CD is a column of type VARCHAR

Comment: I have also tried using Add like --> myCommand.Parameters.Add("@DELYN", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "NO";
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@USER_CD", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "01";

Comment: If you hard-code the values in the SQL, i.e. `SELECT NAME FROM USERS WHERE DELYN='NO' AND USER_CD='01'` does that fine them? What happens if you run that same query in SQL Management Studio?

Comment: I have just tried that surprisingly it is working just great in SQL Mgt Studio even if I hard code the DELYN and USER_CD values it is working

Comment: Okay, so that query works in SQL Management Studio without parameters - what happens in your C# code if you try the exact same thing? (I'm not sure why it's a surprise that that works, btw.)

Comment: I am surprised why its working with hard coded values but failing with parameters in my C# code isn't it recommended that I use parameters?

Comment: Parameters are more important for user input rather than hard-coded values. But I'll only be surprised if we find that the same query works **in your C# code** without parameters. Otherwise, I suspect there's some other reason why it works in SQL Management Studio, e.g. because you're actually querying a different database.

Comment: But it is also working in my C# code with hard coded values;its displaying DB data according to the query(when I use hard coded values) which is why I think the DB is correct only maybe the parameters are the ones making the query fail to execute properly

Comment: Okay. That's very odd then. There's nothing obviously wrong with how you've specified those parameters.